# What happened to the family photos?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In *The Walking Dead* season 3 episode 12 "Clear", Carl risks his life to get a picture of his deceased mother from the local watering hole. He describes it as the last surviving picture of Lori, and he wants his sister Judith to know what her mom looked like.

Back in season 1, we know that Lori took her family photos with her when she was evacuated. In fact, Rick knew that his family left their house safely because all of their family albums were missing. When Rick and Lori are reunited again, they share a moment where they browse through those photos.

So sometime between these two incidents the photos were either destroyed or misplaced.

I can't remember, but were we ever shown what happened to the old Grimes family albums?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming they were destroyed in Herschel's farmhouse fire that terminated the last season. Rick and Lorie were living there with Carl. They would not have been able to be retrieved as that season finale was devoted to escaping the zombie swarm.

Answer (score 0):

Lori had a few photos in 1 album, but a webisode showed the Grimes family belongings in storage. Around the 3.5 minute mark.
http://www.amctv.com/the-walking-dead/videos/webisode-2-the-walking-dead-cold-storage-keys-to-the-kingdom
If Carl knew this was there, then maybe he can remember and go back one day.